# How can I create a hierarchical datagrid in asp.net (.net 2.0) using VB.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, datagridview

How can I create a similar hierarchical datagrid in asp.net (.net 2.0) using VB.net
Please see the image here.[image]
This is the gridview, which is shown after the conversion wizard. How it is desgined(it's like a hirerachial). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link [Asp.Net Hierarchical GridView](http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=125&Desc=Asp.Net-Hierarchical-GridView) for vb.net implementation and for more information and reference check the following links:
[hierarchical grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594160/hierarchical-grid)
[ASP.NET - Hierarchical grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295607/asp-net-hierarchical-grid-view)
[Hierarchical treeview implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727079/hierarchical-treeview-implementation)

Hope this help..

Comment: yes. i have implemented with some third party control, they are also using same approach. it is using datagrid in the `<ItemTemplate>` or `RowTemplates` etc..

Comment: Yes its worked. We need to simply set relation as what we doing for a nested Repeater. :)